# Tire chains list my tire size as supported but seem incredibly tight (can't get them on properly

Tags: snow-chain

Dealing with diamond pattern tire chains of this type: https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/passenger-diamond-back-square-link-chain-0301240p.0301234.html?colorCode=MANUFACTURER_PART_NUM_1555Q#nl-product-details

The ones where you have these plastic tubes that you connect behind the tire.

My tires from the 2019 Honda Odyssey Touring are 235/55R19, which is listed on the package of the tire chains I got.

But after doing the first step of linking the "tubes" behind the wheel, and linking the "yellow" chains at the front, I cannot possibly get the red chain through the cam...

Am I missing some gotchas, or could it be that the chains are too small even if my size is listed?

Providing visual reference for what I'm talking about:

[image]

In this picture, there's a green (teal?) connected at top, and then in red there's the cam and two rings.

What happens in my case, after I hook up the green thing, that the cam and the "bungee" chain are so far apart that I can't really get it through. So, the yellow chain, instead of making a nice circle with a diameter roughly that of the rims, is sitting way at the back.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong *before* I attempt to connect them?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It has been a long time since I've dealt with chains, but my first thought is you should take them completely off and start over. I don't know if it will help, but it sure couldn't hurt at this point.

Comment: Being trained in the art of computer programming, that is exactly how I proceeded :D 

I'll try some more tonight and maybe post pictures. I got the red chain (with the bungee thing) through the cam, but then I definitely don't have enough slack to get it through any of those rings.

Comment: The first time I put new chains on it was a real pain in the you-know-what. But I'd rather have them tight than loose...

Comment: For sure. Just not so tight that I can't even get them on ‍♂️ :)